# Header file for the OpencCV function DenseOpticalFlow::calc

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to find the header file for the function DenseOpticalFlow::calc but I haven't been succesful so far. My system is Ubuntu 12.04 and my OpenCv version is 2.4.1 .

This is the error I'm getting in my terminal:

```
Optical-Flow-Demo-modified.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
Optical-Flow-Demo-modified.cpp:79:3: error: ‘DenseOpticalFlow’ has not been declared
```

Can anyone tell me where I can find the header file for DenseOpticalFlow::calc?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/video.html

Comment: 2.4.1 probably only has the old c-api version of this. update to 2.4.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the declaration in video/tracking.hpp in the opencv include directory. My system is Mac OS X Lion, and OpenCV version is 2.4.7.

Comment: The header file tracking.hpp in my Open Cv version  (2.4.1) doesn't contain the declaration of DenseOpticalFlow::calc. It looks like the function doesn't exist on my version.  Thank you for your help.